# Is it possible to save Kable tables to PDF with macOS Catalina?

Tags: r-markdown, adobe, macos-catalina, kable

I use the kableExtra package all the time to create tables in R Markdown and save them to PDF. However today I upgraded to MacOS Catalina and now when I export to PDF, I cannot open the PDF image and get the error, "insufficient data for an image" in Adobe Reader. I don't get an error message in R Markdown and the PDF appears in my files, but I cannot open it in Adobe. If I use another application to open it (i.e., Preview) the resolution is very poor - and not typical of PDF. Has anyone else run into this problem and is there a solution? Many thanks for your help!

My code to retrieve the error is below:

```
mtcars %>%
kable() %>%
kable_styling() %>%
save_kable("test.pdf")
```

And session info is:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] metafor_2.1-0      Matrix_1.2-18      MASS_7.3-51.5      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 tidyr_1.0.2        knitr_1.28        
 [7] sandwich_2.5-1     plotROC_2.2.1      ggROC_1.0          pROC_1.16.1        dplyr_0.8.4        plyr_1.8.5        
[13] foreign_0.8-75     gridExtra_2.3      kableExtra_1.1.0   scales_1.1.0       ggplot2_3.2.1      psych_1.9.12.31   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3        lattice_0.20-38   ps_1.3.2          zoo_1.8-7         utf8_1.1.4        assertthat_0.2.1 
 [7] digest_0.6.24     R6_2.4.1          evaluate_0.14     httr_1.4.1        highr_0.8         pillar_1.4.3     
[13] rlang_0.4.4       lazyeval_0.2.2    rstudioapi_0.11   callr_3.4.2       magick_2.3        rmarkdown_2.1    
[19] labeling_0.3      webshot_0.5.2     readr_1.3.1       stringr_1.4.0     munsell_0.5.0     compiler_3.6.2   
[25] xfun_0.12         pkgconfig_2.0.3   mnormt_1.5-6      htmltools_0.4.0   tidyselect_1.0.0  tibble_2.1.3     
[31] fansi_0.4.1       viridisLite_0.3.0 crayon_1.3.4      withr_2.1.2       grid_3.6.2        nlme_3.1-144     
[37] jsonlite_1.6.1    gtable_0.3.0      lifecycle_0.1.0   magrittr_1.5      cli_2.0.1         stringi_1.4.6    
[43] farver_2.0.3      xml2_1.2.2        vctrs_0.2.2       tools_3.6.2       glue_1.3.1        purrr_0.3.3      
[49] hms_0.5.3         processx_3.4.2    parallel_3.6.2    yaml_2.2.1        colorspace_1.4-1  rvest_0.3.5
```